# Re-binding vue.js component

Tags: vue.js

I've got a custom Vue component that is successfully bound to a javascript object, but now would like to re-bind the component to another object. Is this possible?

Markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <p v-component="user-profile" v-with="user"></p>
</div>
```

With the following component / vue:

```
Vue.component('user-profile', {
  template: '{{name}}<br>{{email}}'
})

var parent = new Vue({
  el: '#wrapper',
  data: {
    user: {
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      email: 'foo@bar.com'
    }
  }
})
```

I'd like to re-bind the component with the following data:

```
user: {
  name: 'Baz',
  email: 'baz@vue.com'
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. It sounds like you just want to change the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
parent.user = {
   name: 'Baz',
   email: 'baz@vue.com'
};
```